# How to get a WCF reference to generate references for classes that aren't used by function calls?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, .net-4.0

I have a WCF service (Service1) and a project (Project1) that references/uses that service. If I have a class declared in Service1, but don't use it in a function call, I can't use the class in Project1. I assume it's not building the required refernece, is there a way to force this (aside from making that class be used in a function)?

Comment: Can you show us how your implementing your service? How does your service methods look like. Did you add the service reference to your project?

Comment: Did you mark your class with the Data Contract attribute and the members with the related Data Member attribute?  See [Using Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx).  If you don't need the class for exchanging data, I'd suggest putting it in a separate assembly that both the service and the project can use, but you'll probably want to use Data Contracts.

Comment: @Tim The reason I want to do this is I have a function that might return one of several different object types, so I wanted to just have it return a type and an object, and cast it accordingly. It's a function that you pass a barcode to, but the barcode can be for  lots of different things. I was trying to do this without a different function for each barcode type (since the caller doesn't know what type of barcode it is)